# Plotly: Two x-axis (same y-axis) on python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to use 2 xaxis (same yaxis) on a plot. Basically, I want to have different labels on the top X-axis and the bottom X-axis, and I thought it would be possible by creating 2 traces, with one of them being empty but using its xaxis. I have checked similar examples with 2 yaxis, but doing it with 2 xaxis does not seem to work.

Basically, I would like to have the following plot, but with different labels in the top x-axis:

[image]

```py
import plotly
import numpy as np

outputFile = "out.html"
cols=10
rows=100

dataD = np.random.rand(10,100)

names = ["name1", "name2","name3","name4","name5",\
             "name6", "name7","name8","name9","name10"]
nums = ["2", "3","1","2","12","3", "2","28","1","40"]

final_data1=[]
final_data2=[]

for i in range(dataD.shape[0]):

    conf = {
        "type": "violin",
        "x0": names[i],
        "y": dataD[i,:],
        "name": names[i],
        "xaxis": "x1",
        "yaxis": "y"
    }
    final_data1.append(conf)
    topNum= {
        "type": "violin",
        "x0": nums[i],
        "y": [],
        "showlegend": False,
        "xaxis": "x2",
        "yaxis": "y"
    }
    final_data2.append(topNum)

fig = {
    "data": [final_data1,final_data2],
    "layout" : {
        "title": "Random title",
        "xaxis": {
            "showgrid":True,
            "showline":True,
            "tickangle": 270,
            "side":"bottom",
            "anchor": "y"
        },
        "xaxis2":{
            "overlaying":"x1",
            "side":"top",
            "anchor": "y"
        },
        "yaxis": {
            "zeroline": False,
        },
        "hovermode": "closest"
    }
}
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename=outputFile, validate = False)
```

This is the output, and it is obviously wrong (I do not even understand why the labels go from -1 to 6):

[image]

Cheers